# How to systematically find out which planes vectors occupy.

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I am trying to write a program that given n vectors returns how many planes the vectors can occupy. Usually I visualize the vectors in my head to do this but I am unsure of how to do this numerically and so on.

For example
`[4,1]` can cover the entire xy plane and `[0,1]` can only cover the entire y plane and so on.

Another case is involving how many planes multiple vectors can cover together. Like how many planes can `[0,1,1]` and `[0,0,2]` cover together. I can do this by sketching and in my head but I am not sure how to convey this logic in numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "`[4,1]`"? And how does it "cover" the entire $xy$ plane?

Comment: Apologies, I was unclear. Suppose we have a vector like [4,1] and another [3,7] the linear combinations of those two vectors can represent any point in the xy plane. Am I incorrect here?

Comment: Yes. Those two vectors do not lie on the same line, so the space of all linear combinations of them will form a plane. Since they are 2D, that plane is all of $\Bbb R^2$ (2D space). The same is true of your 3D example. They are two vectors that do not lie on the same line (through the origin) so their linear combinations will form a plane in 3D space (the plane passing through each and the origin). If you add a third vector in the same plane, you get nothing more. But if the third vector is not in that plane, the linear combinations will be all of 3D space.

Comment: I see, is there also a way to write an algorithm that can determine the power of R or can it only be computed by hand?

Comment: Count the number of elements in your vectors. That is the dimension of the space they are in. They cannot span a higher dimensional space than that, though they may span a space of smaller dimension (The set of all possible linear combinations of a set $B$ of vectors is called the "span" of $B$.) The dimension of the span of $B$ also cannot be higher than the number of vectors in $B$. To find out the dimension of $\text{span}(B)$, throw out any vectors in $B$ that are linear combinations of the others. When you are done, the dimension will be the number of vectors remaining.